# Elevation possible or not?

Tags: c++, windows, uac, elevation

I have some problems with UAC, I want to find out if it is enabled or disabled.

That's all I know:

- XP and older have UAC **disabled** by default.
- On Vista, Server 2008 and 7 I can check the EnableLUA registry value.
- 8 has UAC **enabled** by default.

But how the situation looks like on Windows 10?

Please correct me if I'm wrong with the points above, I'm dealing with this annoying UAC from 2 weeks and I couldn't find anything concrete.

PS. I'm making auto-elevation system, when the application run it should check is elevation possible or not, if elevation is possible then auto-elevate or if isn't then run with user privileges.

I'll really appreciate any help.

Comment: To my understanding, XP doesn't have UAC disabled but simply completely lacks any of the UAC concepts.

Comment: There is an article [UAC self-elevation (CppUACSelfElevation)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppUACSelfElevation-981c0160). Did you happen to come across it during your research?

Comment: @Uwe Keim I mean when I run on XP I will get admin privileges if the user is admin, if I will run with user privileges I couldn't do anything to get admin.

Comment: @Oswald Yup, but there isn't anything about Win10.

Comment: Why can't you just attempt to elevate, and then run as user if the attempt fails?  I'm fairly sure that's the usual approach.

Comment: You can self elevated during run-time when needed. See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320748/Haephrati-Elevating-during-runtime) article.